# Activity/navigation strategy for browsing a folders tree

Tags: android, android-activity

I have to implement a tree browser in Android. For this particular case, the tree will be a folders hierarchy. So the user will start in a root directory, and will be able to browse the whole hierarchy.

I have experience in iOS development, and this could be done using a `UINavigationController`, pushing a new controller each time the user taps a folder, but I am not sure if using the same strategy in Android is the right thing to do.

My first idea is to have a `FolderViewActivity`, create the first one with the root path, and every time the user taps a folder, create a new one with the new path. So you have a stack of activities, and if the user wants to go up, the current activity will be finished and the previous one will be shown.

Is this the right approach? Could be any problems with the back button doing this?

I have seen a few projects in github implementing a file browser, and it seems that everybody tries to reuse a single activity for doing everything, updating an adapter with new data when the user taps a folder. For me this is a poor implementation, unless there is a good reason for doing it (something Android specific?)

Answer (score 0):

In Android you should use as less activities as you can. `Activity` is quite expensive object and it should be instantiate only if you need specific context with some different settings (orientation, action bar) or if you want to do some new things (for example, editing file content or displaying settings).

When you navigate through file tree you actually do the same action every time: show directory content with some path. For this routine you should use such lightweight and reusable objects as `Fragment`s (http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

The benefits of such approach are: less memory, less expensive calls (create or destroy activity), more fast, more flexible, you can handle back button press as you like.

So you should not create a stack of activities, you should create one activity and then replace fragments for every new folder.

Comment: what can you say about this? https://corner.squareup.com/2014/10/advocating-against-android-fragments.html

Comment: There are always many pros and contras, but write with fragments)

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing the same using a recyclerview. No need for fragments or activities. Firs load the root, after a click you need to update the adapter of the recycler view with the new child objects. You can keep a navigation stack in order to have a navigation back strategie.

Comment: When the user goes back, how do you keep the scroll status of the previous folder? And what happens if the content is received from a server (including images and this kind of things)? Do you have to model all of this in your navigation stack?

Comment: I have Stack with the minimum of informations that I need for the navigation (folder Id and folder name). If you receive something from the server you should reload the data and display the updated adapter. The recyclerview is very flexible and allows you to do everything.